# Put multiple divs on same line using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm currently working with Django, and i'm doing a view, where multiple objects from a list are displayed. Right now, each of those objects is on an own line. But i want to have e.g. 2 on one line, so the list is less long on the page.

This is my Code so far:

html:

```
{% for plant in plants %}
<div class="plant">
    <img src="{{plant.icon}}">
    <div>
        <label>{{plant.common_name}}</label>
        <input type="number" name="percentage"/>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

CSS:

```
.plant_beet_form {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
.plant div {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.plant input{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.plant img {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.plant {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

I already tried using `display:grid` and `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr`, but this didn't work either. Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry i forgot this, around the {% if %}, there is a class called plant_beet_form, which is pretty much just the list

Comment: Just loop it in a table row with 2 `td`s

Comment: I believe you need to use `grid-template-columns : 1fr 1fr`, if you want to put 2 on one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try this:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="plant">
<img src="{{plant.icon}}">
</div>
<div>
    <label>{{plant.common_name}}</label>
    <input type="number" name="percentage"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:
I added the following:

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `grid-template-columns : 1fr 1fr` in the Parent `Div` for example if the parent div of your content is `.plant_beet_form` then do this.

```
.plant_beet_form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

And style your `.plant` class as you need after that